# Run Eclipse Plugin Activator's .start() Method on UI Thread

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

The specification of the [AbstractUIPlugin](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fplugin%2FAbstractUIPlugin.html) states that the `startup` method can't assume that it's run on the UI thread. Is this also true of the `start` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start` method is not a suitable place to put UI code. Amongst other things it is not normally called until some other code in your plugin runs.

The JavaDoc for `Plugin` where `start` is defined says:

> This method and the stop(BundleContext) may be called from separate
>   threads, but the OSGi framework ensures that both methods will not be
>   called simultaneously.

which does not really guarantee which thread `start` will run on.